# Sharepoint 2013 PowerView report depending on connected user

Tags: sharepoint, ssas, powerview

I'm working on a power view map to display to our user. I achieved to create a map that display all the data to the user. It look like [this exemple](http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/295/How-to-create-a-Power-View-Map-SharePoint-2013-Business-Intelligence-site.html). The data source is an SSAS project. 
But now, I would like to filter this data depending on the connected user.

For example, we have ProductManager and TerritoryManager. The product manager can see his product on all the map, but only his product. The territory mananger can see all the product, but only on his territory.

The solution that I've found is to create an SSAS project for each product/territory, and after that allow some rights on this files. But this solution is impossible to maintain.

Is there a way/solution/best practice to realize this?
Any help is welcome

Damien

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need one SSAS database. You can set security in the SSAS project. If you are using SSAS multidimensional, see [here](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event10/Advanced_Security_with_Analysis_Services_Multidimensional). For tabular, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127437.aspx).

As long as you have [Kerberos configured](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1406.kerberos-for-microsoft-bi-with-delegation-and-spn-references-for-sql-ssrs-ssas-and-sharepoint.aspx), you can have one Power View map and one SSAS source. Then when the user accesses the report, their credentials are passed along with the query, and only the data they are allowed to see will be returned. This will meet the needs you described.

You'll probably want to add a table to facilitate dynamic security. You'll need some way to tie product managers to the products they own and territory managers to the territories they own. You add this to the data in the SSAS model. And then use it to set security. Other than setting the data source for Power View to use Windows authentication, no changes are required to the report.